# Lenovo T510 Keyboard Removal

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

I've removed the bottom ram cover, and the two keyboard screws from below.  Supposedly, the next step is to push down and forward on the keyboard.

However, when I do this the keyboard does not move at all.  I've tried applying a fairly good bit of pressure, but there is still no movement.

Are there any tricks to getting this to come off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThinkPad fanboy to the rescue!

You can see the official Lenovo service vidoes here, including one for keyboard removal:

http://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/ion/W510/index.html

As the video only shows that what you need to do is what you are already trying, you can assume that something has just got a bit stuck, and so you just need to apply a bit of extra force - carefully.  Try using a small screwdriver at the top edge of the keyboard, as a lever to get it to budge.

Comment: Yay... you were right.  It looks like the top part of the keyboard (closest to the screen) was slightly out of position, and had it wedged in at an odd angle.  Once it popped loose, it slid out easily.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try watching the video here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh72RpMyVKc&playnext=1&list=PL19465AC62333E47E

It shows you exactly what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm trying to do... it's just not working.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rc2rGryt2Fg#t=3m18s) gave me a tip that seems to work well: if you look underneath the keys at the bottom-right and bottom-left edges of the keyboard, you can see a little metal ridge in the crack between the keys and the bezel. (It helps to use a flashlight.) You can stick your (small flat-head) screwdriver under this metal ridge (which is actually the edge of the keyboard assembly) and use a bit of leverage on the right side and then the left, and the keyboard pretty much pops out. (The computer in the video is a T410, but the T510 is the same in this respect.) Here's a picture I just took in case you can't view that video:

[image: Close-up photograph of the bottom edge of a T510 keyboard]